# issue using mysql with union all

Tags: mysql

```
 select `C1`.`ID` AS `ID`,
`C1`.`Article_ID` AS `Article_ID`,
`C1`.`DateAdded` AS `DateAdded`,
`C1`.`Votes` AS `Votes`,
`C1`.`Content` AS `Content`,
(select 0) AS `isReply`,
`C1`.`Usr_ID` AS `Usr_ID`,
(select NULL) AS `RepliedTo` 
from `Comment` as C1
where isnull(`C1`.`Reply_ID`) limit 5
UNION ALL
select 
`C2`.`Reply_ID` AS `Reply_ID`,
`C2`.`Article_ID` AS `Article_ID`,
`C2`.`DateAdded` AS `DateAdded`,
`C2`.`Votes` AS `Votes`,
`C2`.`Content` AS `Content`,
`C2`.`ID` AS `isReply`,
`C2`.`Usr_ID` AS `Usr_ID`,
`C2`.`RepliedTo` AS `RepliedTo` 
from `Comment` as C2
where (`C2`.`Reply_ID` = `C1`.`Reply_ID` )
```

My issue is in the last line  `where (C2.Reply_ID = C1.Reply_ID )` in specific the `C2.Reply_ID=C1.Reply_ID`

an Error with `Unknown column C1.Reply_ID in where clause` is popping out.

My Objective is that I want to Retrieve

All rows of Table1

Union All

The rows of Table2 using the ID's retrieved from Table1 in where clause

Comment: to use `UNION ALL` you should wrap the arguments in brackets, such as `(argument1) UNION ALL (argument 2)`

Comment: @Martin its doesn't matter in fact

Comment: You are constraining the `Reply_Id` to be `NULL` in the first subquery and then using an equality condition on that column in the second.  The answer is obvious:  the second query returns no rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I agree, any ideas about a solution ?

Comment: Ask another question.  Provide sample data and desired results.  A SQL Fiddle is always helpful.  You need to frame the question to fix the problem about `reply_id`.  We can't really help there.

Comment: @GordonLinoff when using UNION ALL does the table lock ? I mean let's say I have applied the solution of  Jens and while the second Table was retrieving the first 5 rows , someone has inserted some new row  to comment will it choose the new row inserted ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the tables from the first select in the second select.

You have to repeat your first query in the second select query

```
select `C1`.`ID` AS `ID`,
`C1`.`Article_ID` AS `Article_ID`,
`C1`.`DateAdded` AS `DateAdded`,
`C1`.`Votes` AS `Votes`,
`C1`.`Content` AS `Content`,
(select 0) AS `isReply`,
`C1`.`Usr_ID` AS `Usr_ID`,
(select NULL) AS `RepliedTo` 
from `Comment` as C1
where isnull(`C1`.`Reply_ID`) limit 5
UNION ALL
select 
`C2`.`Reply_ID` AS `Reply_ID`,
`C2`.`Article_ID` AS `Article_ID`,
`C2`.`DateAdded` AS `DateAdded`,
`C2`.`Votes` AS `Votes`,
`C2`.`Content` AS `Content`,
`C2`.`ID` AS `isReply`,
`C2`.`Usr_ID` AS `Usr_ID`,
`C2`.`RepliedTo` AS `RepliedTo` 
from `Comment` as C2
where (`C2`.`Reply_ID` in (select `C1`.`ID` 
from `Comment` as C1
where isnull(`C1`.`Reply_ID`) limit 5)
```

Comment: also, he's trying to use an equality compare on a column he's already constrained to be null.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer @Jens what about the performance of such code ?

Comment: I don't think this does what the OP wants.  There is no guarantee that the five rows returned in the first subquery will be chosen in the second (even after the other syntax errors are fixed).

Comment: You can use the same table multiple times in a UNION so long as it is not a TEMPORARY table... the problem with the question's query is that the second query's WHERE is referencing the first query, which is not allowed... which is maybe what you were trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you close to what you want:

```
SELECT `ID` AS `ID`
   , `Article_ID` AS `Article_ID`
   , `DateAdded` AS `DateAdded`
   , `Votes` AS `Votes`
   , `Content` AS `Content`
   , IF(copyTbl.copyNum=1, 0, `ID`) AS `isReply`
   , `Usr_ID` AS `Usr_ID`
   , IF(copyTbl.copyNum=1, NULL, `RepliedTo`) AS `RepliedTo` 
FROM `Comment`, (SELECT 1 AS copyNum UNION SELECT 2) AS copyTbl
WHERE `Reply_ID` IS NULL
ORDER BY `ID`, copyTbl.copyNum
LIMIT 10
;
```

It assumes `Comment`.`ID` is unique; if that is not the case, you'll need to adjust the `ORDER BY` accordingly.